# Serilog file ordering

Tags: logging, configuration, serilog

I'm currently logging using serilog with rollOnFileSizeLimit and want to change the order of the files.

At present the order of the log files is as follows:

*Oldest*
log.txt
log1.txt
log2.txt
...
*Youngest*

I'd like to switch this round:

*Oldest*
...
log2.txt
log1.txt
log.txt
*Youngest*

I've read the configuration pages for both serilog and the file sink and this isn't listed as a possibility. Does anyone know if it is possible?

This is the configuration we're running:

```
.WriteTo.File(
     logFilePath,
     shared: true,
     fileSizeLimitBytes: 1024 * 1024,
     rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
     retainedFileCountLimit: 100,
     outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.fff}..."
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Serilog.Sinks.File`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/tree/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File) does not have this feature. [The sequence is coded to be in ascending order](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/Sinks/File/RollingFileSink.cs#L178).

If you want this feature, you could [submit a pull-request](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/pulls), or create your own modified version of the sink.

Comment: @jamesdrinkwater read https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/40 first though as a) there is an impl b) there are reasons to not do this